# Is it possible to connect to an app that uses azure AD using on-premises credentials without seeing login screen at all?

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

The client requirement is that after the user login to their computer using the on-premises active directory, the user will be able to access our web-app that is hosted on azure without the user ever needing to see the login screen again.

I understood that we will need to use AD connect and AD FS but I understood that the user will still need to login at least once.

Am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understood that we will need to use AD connect and AD FS but I understood that the user will still need to login at least once.

No. With federation sign on, you can enable users to sign on to Azure AD based services with their on-premises passwords and, **while on the corporate network, without having to enter their passwords again**.( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectfed-whatis))

Comment: Thx. But I am still trying to understand  : After a user logged in to his computer with his password , when this user try to enter our app , he will see a sign on page at least for the first time . Right?

Comment: Yes, by default we still need to enter the username/password for onetime. If you want to login-in automatically using the domain credential you have to need to setup other settings.( refer [SSO when on the intranet from a domain joined machine, logged in with a domain credential](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/abizerh/2013/04/11/more-information-about-sso-experience-when-authenticating-via-adfs/))

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no.
Azure AD definitely asks the user to re authenticate once the token is expired.

If your application is supposed to work as a stand alone app without any client interaction, you can register your app as a daemon app using a certificate.

It is a definite risk if you are giving the application to the customer. Generally, this method is used between the applications which belong to the same internal network and owned by the same organization.

You can refer below for more info
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential/